# Fastest way to find firstIndex in a large array (1,000) Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, filter, instruments

Is there a faster way to find the index in an array of custom object?

I have an array which has a count of approximately 1,000. And within each SectionIndex there is a MainIndex with all my properties, each SectionIndex has approximately 15 MainIndex parts. SectionIndex is used for TableView section headings and the .data[MainIndex] part fills the rows within each section.

After running instruments (Time Profiling) of the 5 seconds taken to start my app the (array.firstIndex) line has taken 3.89 seconds, is there anyway I can speed up the part where I find the index?

```
var array: [SectionIndex] = [SectionIndex]()
```

Main part in the function:

```
let title = "\(dateMonth), \(dateYear)"
if let offset = array.firstIndex(where: { $0.title == title })
{
     array[offset].data.append(insert)
     if let mins = array[offset].minutes {
     array[offset].minutes = mins + timeToMinutes(minutes)
     }
}
else
{
     let insert2 = SectionIndex(index: array.count, title: title, date: date, data: [insert], minutes: timeToMinutes(minutes))
     array.append(insert2)
}
```

SectionIndex

```
class SectionIndex {
let index: Int?
let title: String?
let date: Date?
var data: [MainIndex] = [MainIndex]()
var minutes: Int?
init(index: Int, title: String, date: Date, data: [MainIndex], minutes: Int)
{
    self.index = index
    self.title = title
    self.date = date
    self.data = data
    self.minutes = minutes
}
}
```

Reason why I need to find or add the index:

My data is from different months of the year going back around 1,000 months, whenever the month and year is found first it becomes a title, next time when it already exists I append the data to that Section.

Xcode 12.2 (Swift 5)

Comment: If something takes a long time, don’t do it on the main thread during launch. Launch needs to be fast.

Comment: How often is this `array.firstIndex` called? 3.9 seconds seems _way_ too much time, unless you call it extremely often. Also, as an aside, are you sure the properties in `SectionIndex` need to be Optionals? Judging from the `init` you show you can get rid of all of those `?` marks.

Comment: Yeah, multiple seconds for only 1000 items is inconceivable. There’s something else going on. (By the way, I assume you are profiling release/optimized builds, right?)

Comment: Are there some nested loops or something like that in your real code. There’s no way that a single search would take that long, but I wonder if you’re doing this repeatedly. In answer to your question, ways to speed it up are to improve the search to O(1) (e.g. using dictionary, your own hash tables, etc.). But it doesn’t feel like we have enough to diagnose what’s going on...

Comment: Yes, so basically since I have 1,000 sections to add and 15 entries per section. There is total of 15,000 entries in the database, so this line runs 15,000 times to check if the title exists or needs adding.

Comment: Reason why it’s in the main thread on launch is because that’s the main data the user has to see. It is only this slow when the user reaches 15,000 which is maximum. It’s much quicker when the number is less. But I’m testing with worst case scenario to have to lowest loading time. Re optionals that’s true, that will actually save another fraction of a second from unwrapping a lot of optionals.

Comment: If it takes a few seconds, it is almost always better to (a) present a spinner (e.g. a `UIActivityIndicatorView`); (b) do it in the background; and (c) remove the spinner and update the model and UI on the main thread when it is done. It lets the user know that the app isn’t frozen, and avoids the risk of the watchdog process killing an unresponsive app. Clearly, if you can speed it up, as you have, that’s great. But anything that takes more than a few milliseconds should almost always should be done on a background thread. But I’m glad you found a good solution to the slow, blocking, process.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean, i did originally think of having a loading animation, but the issue is, when data entries are below 6,000 or iPhone XS Max, the animation would appear and disappear as it happens fast. Issue only comes which will be rare when user start reaching maximum data. I guess I could have both options dependent on loading time? Once the function time is above a threshold value I could store a slow loading variable which then would trigger loading animation on each launch. Btw thanks for your help, the time I saved on loading is amazing, just with a use of dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments suggestions and Rob's dictionary suggestion, I have adapted the following, which solved my problem and improved performance by a lot!

```
 var currentIndex: Int = 0
 var dic: [String: Int] = [:]

 // Code below runs 15,000 times for each database entry
 if let offset = dic[title]
 {
     array[offset].data.append(insert)
     if let mins = array[offset].minutes { array[offset].minutes = mins + timeToMinutes(minutes) }
 }
 else
 {
       let insert2 = SectionIndex(index: currentIndex, title: title, date: date, data: [insert], minutes: timeToMinutes(minutes))
       dic[title] = currentIndex
       currentIndex += 1
       array.append(insert2)
 }
```

I have also got rid of the optionals in my main part with a lot of entries which further improved the loading performance. Results with the above:

> Main Thread: 1.91s
>
> Start: 1.77s
>
> System Interface Initialisation: 1.29s
>
> UIKit Initialisation: 933 ms
>
> Launching Initial Frame Rendering: 1.64s

I'm happy with the result as that's per worst case of loading 15,000 entries in to 1,000 sections, but if anyone has any further suggestions and improvements let me know.